# Why $I \times I $ is not convex in $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$?

Tags: general-topology

The followings are from Munkers' Topology:

[image]

and

[image]

Although I didn't understand Theorem 16.4 but I totally understand the Example 3 above and I believe it's correct. The problem is that $I \times I $ is convex in $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ and is it a contradiction to the Theorem 16.4?

Comment: $I\times I$ is not convex in $R\times R$.

Comment: (You are probably mixing definitions... Convex has aat least two meanings, the one used by Munkres and [the more usual one involving segments and so on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$I\times I$ is not convex in $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$ under the order topology. For example, $(\frac12,42)$ is between $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$.

Comment: Sir , How (1/2,42) is between (0,0) and (1,0)?